# mechanize dealing with errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

you will see through a series of questions I have built a little mechanize task to visit a page() find the links to cafes and save the details of the cafe in a csv.

```
 task :estimateone => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'
  require 'csv'

  mechanize = Mechanize.new
  mechanize.history_added = Proc.new { sleep 30.0 }
  mechanize.ignore_bad_chunking = true
  mechanize.follow_meta_refresh = true
  page = mechanize.get('http://www.siteexamplea.com/city/list/50-city-cafes-you-should-have-eaten-breakfast-at')
  results = []
  results << ['name', 'streetAddress', 'addressLocality', 'postalCode', 'addressRegion', 'addressCountry', 'telephone', 'url']
  page.css('ol li a').each do |link|
   mechanize.click(link)

   name = mechanize.page.css('article h1[itemprop="name"]').text.strip
   streetAddress = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="streetAddress"]').text.strip
   addressLocality = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text.strip
   postalCode = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="postalCode"]').text.strip
   addressRegion = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="addressRegion"]').text.strip
   addressCountry = mechanize.page.css('address span meta[itemprop="addressCountry"]').text.strip
   telephone = mechanize.page.css('address span[itemprop="telephone"]').text.strip
   url = mechanize.page.css('article p a[itemprop="url"]').text.strip
   tags = mechanize.page.css('article h1[itemprop="name"]').text.strip

    results << [name, streetAddress, addressLocality, postalCode, addressRegion, addressCountry, telephone, url]
  end

  CSV.open("filename.csv", "w+") do |csv_file|
    results.each do |row|
      csv_file << row
    end
  end
end
```

when i get to the tenth link I hit a 503 error.

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 503 => Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable for https://www.city.com/city/directory/morning-after -- unhandled response
```

I have tried a couple of things to stop this happening or rescue from this state but I can't work it out. Any tips?

Comment: Try inspecting the Mechanize::ResponseCodeError, if 50x, then add x amount of time for waiting and retry. Or you can try adding just some delay for each url to visit.

Comment: @SebastianPalma isnt that what mechanize.history_added = Proc.new { sleep 30.0 } is doing?

Comment: 503 is a server error. The server didn't like your request. Try making that request in your browser and see what happens. Also, look into debugging proxies like Fiddler or Charles.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks mate, the url does work hence I will check out Fiddler or Charles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to rescue on failed request, [just like here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize/blob/c80200c3f46ce2e41a5787fc49a6ccd01cf0919d/examples/spider.rb)

```
task :estimateone => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'
  require 'csv'

  begin
  # ...
  page = mechanize.get('http://www.theurbanlist.com/brisbane/a-list/50-brisbane-cafes-you-should-have-eaten-breakfast-at')
  rescue Mechanize::ResponseCodeError
    # do something with the result, log it, write it, mark it as failed, wait a bit and then continue the job
    next
  end
end
```

My guess is that you're hitting API rate limits. This will not solve your problem as it is not in your side but at the server's; but will give you range to work as now you can flag the links that did not work and continue from there on.

Comment: than you this is great

Comment: could you show me how to add this to the above code